# angular validate input type=“number” validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I was having an issue with `input type number validation` when user enters character.

It just got disappear when user tab out.

After little reseach i found couple of solutions and the best one is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395188/angular-validate-input-type-number)

The solution given here is to use the following directive

```
app.directive('toNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return parseFloat(value || '');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This solution works fine if user try to enter 1st character other than number. However it does not work when user enters `lets say 1W`. It allows to enter this pattern.

Probably, i need to modify this directive to blovk `1W, 1.W, 1WWW (any character after valid number)` patterns to be blocked from entering.

Any help?

**Also,**

please share if there is any better solution to what i am looking for.
My problem is: on IE, when user enters character in input type number and tab out, the number just disappear and i am unable to show error using angular $error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this directive

```
userapp.directive('priceValidator', [function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == undefined) return ''
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
}])
```