# Variable length for input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Im using an angular 1 app.
I have this field:

```
<input type="string" maxlength="4" ng-model="account.myNumber" />
```

This field should only accept integers. I think that if I use "type=number" some browser will display the field in a strange way with some kind of selectbox to change the numbers in the field. So I think it's best to have a regex to only allow numbers. 
However, this field has a maxlength of 4 characters ONLY IF the first character is not equal to 0.
If the first entered character is 0, then the maxlength should be 5.
What I wonder if there is some regex to solve this. Or should I let the controller check this? I think it would be neater with a regex if it is possible to let it calculate that.

Comment: Mm it is not working. I can enter letters and there is no limit for number of chars: <input type="string" name="noname" ng-pattern="/^0?[0-9]{4}$/" >

Comment: ^0[0-9]{4}|(?!0)[0-9]{4}$ this regex can help you with what you need.

Comment: I think this question has been answered
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395188/angular-validate-input-type-number/17396797#17396797">here</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 `pattern` attribute to accomplish this:

```
<input type="string" pattern="^0?[0-9]{0,4}$" ng-model="account.myNumber" />
```